# Exercise with C and pointers

Tags: c

Trying to edit the question so that it is more clear, this code here should print the string and its length, but instead of printing the length of 12, it is only printing 1. The argument (char *s) cannot be changed and the condition of the while loop has to be based on `s = s + 1` increment, though for the length, it still has to return i.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define CADENA_PRUEBA "Hola a todos"

int longitud_string(char *s){
int i;
i=0;
while(*s != '\0')
    s = s + 1;
i++;
return i;
}

int main(void){
char string1[] = CADENA_PRUEBA;  
printf("cadena: %s\n", string1);
printf("longitud cadena: %d\n", longitud_string(string1));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you repeat the question?

Comment: Do you mean `while(*s++ != '\0')` instead of indexing? That's legal.

Comment: The code prints the string and its length. I need to modify this code so that it stills does the same, specifically by adding s = s+1 inside the while loop and then modifying the while condition. But the function still has to return i as the lenght of the string.

Comment: That's what I wrote: `s++` is `s = s + 1` so you can do `while(*s != '\0') { i++; s = s + 1; }`

Comment: it returns lenght of 1 when i do that change

Comment: `%c` is for character not `%s`

Comment: "It returns length of 1 when I do that change" -- Hmmm. I get 12 when I make the change suggested by @WeatherVane to your posted code. Oh, I see that now you have changed the posted code. You are missing the braces around your loop body.

Comment: ... so `i` is incremented only once.

Comment: Please read the comments most carefully. I have edited your code indentation to show your mistake more clearly. But in future, please don't convert the question's code to an answer. The flow of comments won't make any sense to someone reading this later.

Comment: This is one reason that many consider it good style to _always_ use braces with loop bodies: `while(*s != '\0') { s = s + 1; i++; }`, and even `while(s[i] != '\0') { i++; }`.

Comment: Thank you soo much @WeatherVane, sorry for the bad practice, this was my very first question in SO, trying to upvote or set your comment as the answer, but still finding out how, but still, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> it is only printing 1

```
int longitud_string(char *s){
int i;
i=0;                   // Set i = 0
while(*s != '\0')
    s = s + 1;
i++;                   // Set i = 1
return i;              // return i (1)
}
```

What you may have wanted is:

```
int longitud_string(char *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(*s != '\0')
    {                 // Need brace here
        s = s + 1;
        i++;          //            Increment both in the loop

    }                 // Close brace here.
    return i;
}
```

But we could simplify it like this:

```
int longitud_string(char *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(s[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let me optimize your code

```
int longitud_string(const char *s)
{
    int i = 0;  // Initialize it with 0
    while(*s)   // No need to check for '\0'
        s++;    // Same as: s = s + 1 or s += 1
    i++;        // Here you increment i only once cause you're outside the scopes of while() loop
    return i;   // Returns i value which is equal to 1 cause it incremented only 1 time.
}
```

You've missed the scopes in your while loop, so your code shall be

```
int longitud_string(const char *s)
{
    int i = 0;  // Initialize it with 0
    while(*s)   // No need to check for '\0'
    {
        s++;    // Same as: s = s + 1 or s += 1
        i++;    // Incrementing every iteration of the loop, now it's working.
    }
    return i;   // Returns the number of iteration of the loop which is equal to the length of (s)
}
```

Now we fixed the problem but we can optimize it more...

```
int getLength(const char* String)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(String != NULL && *String++ && ++i);
    return i;
}
```